# SELECT CASE CAST Conversion Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm querying the back-end of an application.  For what ever reason the developer decided to use NVARCHAR for all fields.  I'm having a problem with one of the "date" fields--somehow it got populated with "97630886".  There's a companion "time" field and for my query I'm trying to concatenate and CAST the results as a DATETIME.  I'm trying to use a CASE statement but it's erroring: "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.". Apparently all conditions are evaluated?  Is there a way I can rewrite my SELECT statement to handle this?

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN LOG_DATE IS NULL AND LOG_TIME IS NULL THEN NULL 
WHEN LOG_DATE IS NULL THEN LOG_TIME 
WHEN LOG_TIME IS NULL THEN LOG_DATE 
WHEN ISDATE(LOG_DATE) = 0 OR ISDATE(LOG_TIME) = 0 THEN LOG_DATE + ' ' + LOG_TIME 
ELSE CAST(LOG_DATE + ' ' + LOG_TIME AS DATETIME)
END AS [LogDateTime] 
FROM ...
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to work `WHEN ISDATE(LOG_DATE) = 0 OR ISDATE(LOG_TIME) = 0 THEN LOG_DATE + ' ' + LOG_TIME ` if `LOG_DATE` contains `97630886`? Regardless of what `LOG_TIME` contains it is never going to concatenate into something that will cast successfully as a datetime?

Comment: My thinking was if neither field had something SQL Server recognized as a date I would just concat the two together and return that--some data is better than none.  I was expecting the CAST() function wouldn't be evaluated since ISDATE('97630886') = 0

Comment: You can't return different `datatypes` from different paths of a case statement. SQL Server will take the one with the highest data type precedence and implicitly cast to that (`DATETIME` has higher precedence than `varchar`). `sql_variant` has a higher precedence than both `varchar` and `datetime` though...

Comment: I see.  Well, since "97630886" is worthless when it comes to reporting back a date, maybe I'll just return NULL for that condition too:

    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN LOG_DATE IS NULL AND LOG_TIME IS NULL THEN NULL 
    WHEN LOG_DATE IS NULL THEN LOG_TIME 
    WHEN LOG_TIME IS NULL THEN LOG_DATE 
    WHEN ISDATE(LOG_DATE) = 0 OR ISDATE(LOG_TIME) = 0 THEN NULL  
    ELSE CAST(LOG_DATE + ' ' + LOG_TIME AS DATETIME)
    END AS [LogDateTime] 
    FROM ...

This doesn't error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix datatypes in CASE expressions (or at least without taking care that they will implicitly cast OK)

when confronted with a stament like the following SQL Server will use datatype precedence to determine what the overall datatype of the expression should be

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'not-a-date' ELSE getdate() END
```

For the above `datetime` has higher precedence than `char` so it implicitly casts the string to a date which fails.

The folowing succeeds however as `sql_variant` [has a higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN cast('not-a-date' as sql_variant) ELSE getdate() END
```

So you can return multiple mixed datatypes that way (I'm not sure how easy `sql_variant` is to work with though)

Other than that you could return `NULL` for invalid datetimes instead of returning the nonsense data or cast everything to a string if you must return it.